# How do I download code from CVS to my local machine

Tags: cvs

I have access to a code repository in CVS. How do I download the code from remote server to my local machine via command line (DOS prompt) on Windows XP machine? I have CVS client installed so am able to run cvs from DOS prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute

```
cvs get blah
```

from the directory where you want to store your code.

Above, blah is the URL for your repository. Alternatively, you can use checkout which is a synonym for get.

Comment: Don't I have to login or set CVSROOT?

Comment: Yes, so you can access the cvs tool. I assumed you had donce that since you indicated you can run it from the command prompt.